# How to sort three different column with 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

```
arr =[[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 11],[2, 6],[3, 9],[3, 12],[4, 4],[4, 7],[5, 1],[5, 10],[6, 5],[7, 8]]
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
for i in range(0,11):
    if arr[i][0] < arr[i+1][0]:
       col1.append(arr[i][0])
    if arr[i][0] == arr[i+1][0]:
       col2.append(arr[i][0])

print(col1)
print(col2)
print(col3)
```

As you can see,It has some same value at arr[i][0] in 2D array.

My idea is every different arr[i][0] values put into the col1.

if it has same values put into the col2.

if it has same values again,put into the col3.

I want output like this...

```
Output: [1 2] [2 6] [3 9] [4 4] [5 1] [6 5] [7 8]
        [1 3]       [3 12][4 7] [5 10]
        [1 11]
```

You maybe say what is this,I try to create One-page Calendar's months sort...

arr[i][0] is weekdays

arr[i][1] is first day correspond on every months

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvk0H.jpg

Comment: the terms of `arr` are not written in python sysntax, please edit it

Comment: what do you mean with the "output like this"? is the print result important or make the right grouping?

Comment: i want make the right grouping

Comment: So...use arrays is impossible succeed?

Comment: what mean is the terms of arr not written in python syntax?

Comment: In your definition of `arr= [[1 2][1 3]...]` will throw a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`... just test it.  You have to put a comma between terms of a list, see my answer

Comment: Oh...I mistaked

Comment: the main problem in your code is that you assume from the beginning that you will have three columns...which is a speculative approach not universal

Answer (score 0):

Using [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard-library. It accepts a callback parameter to describe the grouping condition, in this case wrt the 1st entry. The result will be a list of "columns".

```
from itertools import groupby

arr =[[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 11],[2, 6],[3, 9],[3, 12],[4, 4],[4, 7],[5, 1],[5, 10],[6, 5],[7, 8]]

arr_ordered_by_grps = [list(grp) for _, grp in groupby(arr, key=lambda p: p[0])]

print(arr_ordered_by_grps)
```

---

Using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It is a "more" performant version of the usual dictionary, a subclass to be precise. It groups the terms in `arr` by the first term of the sublist which is used as *key*, hence unique, and appends any other terms with same key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr = # from above

dd = defaultdict(list)
for lst in arr:
    dd[lst[0]].append(lst)

columns = list(dd.values())

# print the output
for col in columns:
    print(col)
```

---

Without any extra imports: use a dictionary to label the groups.

```
arr = # from above

groups= {}
for lst in arr:
    if lst[0] not in groups:
        groups[lst[0]] = [lst]
    else:
        groups[lst[0]].append(lst)

columns = list(groups.values())
```

Comment: i getting to know it...

Comment: this is so hard...i'm stuck